# How to export data from database to xml according the XSD

Tags: sql, xml, xsd

we have an XSD and we want a way to export data in xml format according the XSD. The data now is in a SQL database but we dont have problem to use mysql or other database format. We need to map XSD with table data in order to export them in xml format.

Comment: Hi Alex, There is a good tutorial :http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Table_to_XML_using_SCHEMA_from_XSD

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Got this [from here](http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Table_to_XML_using_SCHEMA_from_XSD)

--Create test table relating to the breakfast menu

```
CREATE TABLE Menus
(name varchar(255)
,price numeric(12,4)
,description varchar(1500)
,calories int);
```

--insert some test data

```
Insert Into Menus Values ('eggs',22.22,'test description eggs',333);
Insert Into Menus Values ('steak',22.22,'test description steak',333);
Insert Into Menus Values ('big side of bacon',22.22,'test description bacon',333);
Insert Into Menus Values ('huge side of bacon',22.22,'test description more bacon',333);
Insert Into Menus Values ('OMG BACON!',22.22,'test description oh man, more bacon',333);
```

XSD schema used to define the export

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="breakfast_menu">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="food">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="name" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="price" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="description" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="calories" type="xs:unsignedShort" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

-- SQL to generate file

```
DECLARE @MenuSchema XML
SET @MenuSchema =   (      
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET        
    (BULK 'C:\Menu.xsd', SINGLE_CLOB)            
        AS xmlData)
--create the schema for using later in the XML type
CREATE XML SCHEMA COLLECTION MenuSchema AS @MenuSchema;

DECLARE @xmlData XML (MenuSchema)
SET @xmlData =
            (SELECT
                [name]
                ,price
                ,[description]
                ,calories
            FROM
            dbo.Menus [food]
            FOR XML AUTO, ROOT ('breakfast_menu'), ELEMENTS)

SELECT @xmlData
```

Comment: This will work in very simple cases only, but I voted it up as it shows some principles...

Answer (score 5):

If your XSD is either "attributes only" or "elements only" it might be enough to use `SELECT ... FOR XML AUTO` with or without `ELEMENTS`.

In most cases - at least in my job - I have do deal with mixed XML.

There is - AFAIK - no automatic way to tell SQL Server: "Hey, here is a query, here is an XSD, go and prepare the fitting XML output!"

You'll have to create a `SELECT ... FOR XML PATH()` which you define in the way, that the output fits your XSD.

Then you declare an XML variable with a given schema and try to fill in the output. This will work - or not. That's the schema validation...

If you find a way to create this automatically please post a comment, thx!

Comment: Yes i agree this. I am also using the same. Export using XML path and using some application written in C# i am validating it. But OP did not add much details so i have done my answer like below.   +1 for the explanation;

Comment: It's been almost 7 years since you said this, is that still the case? :(